# Doing double precision calculation on single precision CPU

Tags: performance, floating-point, embedded, fpu

I wonder what happens on single precision MCU that being asked to do double precision calculation? Is there a known well performace load for such calculation?
Is the integrated single precision unit (FPU) improve performance?

I have big embbedded software that has some double precision calculation and I want to decide a CPU based on higher speed or built in double precision FPU

Comment: Google *long form division*.  The mathematics for [*arbitrary precision* mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), such as [*gmp*](https://gmplib.org/), [*bignum*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html) and others are all based on grade school mathematics.  The same principals apply for floating point (only maybe twice) as you need to perform the same operation on the mantissa and the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

It is a question of what your compiler will do rather than what the processor will do and whether its math library and arithmetic operator implementations make use of the FPU for double precision arithmetic.

I suggest that you build some code for the candidate target with your preferred compiler and take a look at the assembler output.

An alternative is to use fixed point arithmetic. A 64bit 36Q28 fixed point type is good for 19 digits precision overall and and 8 decimal places. The fixed-point library described [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/optimizing-math-intensive-applications-w/207000448) reports a 5 times performance increase over software floating point on ARM which is not dissimilar to the performance increase you'd get using an ARM VFP unit (without SIMD optimisations).  The library is C++ and uses extensive operator and function overloading so that for the most part you can simply replace the keyword `double` with `fixed` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds too hypothetically. It touches a number of theories and practical approaches. Do you have some issue at least of one combination of the software you mentioned and any CPU? If so, it is better to include it to the question so anyone could get more understanding.

If it's more real and serious rather than theoretical discussion and you are about running a serial production, than you definitely should be more concrete with details in your question. Because making things you will need to reduce CPU cost as much as possible and choosing one will be based on a variety of details and/or particular issues in background.

Comment: At this point, I don't want to add other variants to this question. And basiclly want some thumb rules, or other theories of MCU FPU calculations.
The **Best** will be soething like: On a Single FPU MCU, doing double percision Adding "cost" about 20 single percision calculation... Multiply is 30 FPU calculation and another 10 fixed point calcs... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Single precision FPU can't help with double precision operations. On a Single FPU MCU, doing double percision arithmetic leads to the use of software routines. How much does it cost? Depends on the compiler and MCU performance. Anyway you can easily measure it.

Comment: Is that certian that the single point FPU will not assist to the double calculations?

Comment: @matanhavi I have no proof but if you think logically - how can it help? At least in the case of the Cortex-M4F cpu this is true.

Comment: When there is no HW FPU the compiler manipulate the "bits" using its the commands that he have to produce the needed double/single percision caclulation. The better the compiler, it will do that in less ASM caclulations cycles, using the most efficiant comannd of spacific CPU.
The compiler can use the Single percision FPU to manipulate the mantisa or the exponent of the double number, And I have wonder what is the boost in that case.

Comment: @matanhavi **The compiler can use the Single percision FPU to manipulate the mantisa or the exponent of the double number**

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter. I wanted to say that the use of single precision FPU for manipulating mantissa and exponent of double precision number will not bring any benefit. It will be easier to use ordinary additive and multiplicative instructions. Anyway, why you don't want to measure it yourself?

Comment: I want to choose CPU (that I don't have yet) according to that information.

Comment: If you need to perform complex computations at high speed then I suggest you to use DSP or maybe MCU with the full featured double precision FPU. Otherwise forget about FPU at all and let the compiler to choose the best software algorithm. Can you add to your question some information about what you want to do? Approximate number of arithmetic operations, the time for which they should be performed, etc.
Maybe then it will be easier to give you advise.

Comment: @matanhavi: For some iterative-approximation methods, a single-precision FPU might provide a somewhat better "initial guess" than would otherwise be practical, so it wouldn't be totally useless.  On the other hand, for most operations, trying to reconcile the upper portion of a single-precision result with lower bits calculated on the main CPU would probably be no easier than simply computing everything on the main CPU.